# Ordered groups - examples

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, ordered-groups

Let $G=\operatorname{BS}(m,n)$ denote the [Baumslag–Solitar group](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Baumslag%E2%80%93Solitar_group) defined by 
the presentation $\langle a,b: b^m a=a b^n\rangle$.

We assume that $G$ is non-abelian, i.e., $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\smallsetminus\{0\}$ and $(m,n)\neq \pm (1,1)$.

> Question: Find $m,n$ such that $G$ is an [ordered group](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Partially_ordered_group) (in a nontrivial way), i.e. $G$ is a group  on which a (nontrivial) partial order relation $\le $ is given such that for any elements $x,y,z \in G$, from $x \le y$ it follows that $xz \le  yz$ and $zx \le  zy$.

(The trivial partial order is the equality relation.)

Comment: Crossposted at math.SE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365660/ordered-groups-examples

Comment: Do you mean a non-trivial partial order?

Comment: Taking $m, n=1$ has a natural non-trivial ordering. I think you should sharpen your question.

Comment: No exercises here, please.

Comment: Of course, I mean a non-trivial partial order. 


Comment: To Noah: Note that I assume that G is non-abelian. If m=n=1, then G is abelian and the question is trivial.

Comment: Follow-up to Qiaochu's comment: two answers posted on http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365660/ordered-groups-examples

I found the one by Tournesol interesting. Recall that a group of orientation-preserving homeo's of $\mathbb{R}$ admits a total, bi-invariant ordering (with $f\leq g$ iff $f(x)\leq g(x)$ for every $x$). Since $B(m,1)$ embeds in the affine group of $\mathbb{R}$, it admits such an ordering.

Comment: It is safe to write *bi-orderable group* instead of ordered group. Because orderable groups denote, according to authors, either left-orderable or bi-orderable groups and is thus blatantly ambiguous. Also *left/bi-ordered group* is more suitable to mean a group endowed with a (left or bi...)-invariant total order. For instance, there is a Chabauty space of bi-ordered groups on $k$ generators, which surjects onto the Chabauty space of bi-orderable groups on $k$ generators, which is a closed subset of the space of marked groups on $k$ generators.

Comment: @Alain: a countable group admits a *left*-invariant ordering iff it embeds in $Homeo^+(\mathbf{R})$. This proves that the (positive!) affine group of $\mathbf{R}$ is left-orderable. But it is indeed bi-orderable by a general fact on group extensions, here using the fact that the action of the multiplicative group of positive reals on the additive group of reals preserves an ordering.

Comment: Oops, thank you Yves, indeed my remark on $Homeo^+(\mathbb{R})$ is false. One day it will be possible to edit comments on MO.

Comment: Every BS-group $G$ admits an epimorphism $f$ to ${\mathbb Z}$. Pull-back of the order on ${\mathbb Z}$ will give a partial order on $G$ after you declare that distinct elements $x, y\in G$ satisfying $f(x)=f(y)$ are not comparable. 

Comment: In a group $G$, there is a canonical bijection between the set of left-invariant partial preorders $\le$ and the set of submonoids of $G$. It is given by $\le\mapsto S_\le$ and $S\mapsto \le_S$, where $S_\le=\{g:g\ge 1_G\}$ and $g\le_S h$ iff $g^{-1}h\in S$. Then **(a)** $\le$ is nontrivial iff $S_\le\neq\{1_G\}$; **(b)** $\le$ is a order (i.e., antissymetric) iff $S\cap S^{-1}=\{1_G\}$; **(c)** $\le$ is bi-invariant iff $S$ is conjugation-invariant; **(d)** $\le$ is total iff $S\cup S^{-1}=G$. (...)

Comment: (...) In particular, a group admits a nontrivial bi-invariant partial order iff it has a nonempty conjugation-invariant subsemigroup not containing $1$. This is obviously satisfied if it has a $\mathbf{Z}$ quotient, as Misha already said. On the other hand, this does not exist in the infinite dihedral group $D_\infty$. (Side remark: it also follows that a group admits a nontrivial left-invariant partial order iff it is not torsion.)

Answer (score 2):

The Baumslag-Solitar groups $B(1,n)$ for $n\ge 2$ can be ordered, even with a total order.
Indeed, all orderings have been classified in this case, see C. Rivas: On spaces of Conradian group orderings.
Here is one way to obtain an ordering for $B(1,n)$. Start with an exact sequence
$$
0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow BS(1,n) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[1/n]\rightarrow 0,
$$
and define bi-orderings from this:  $(k,r/n^j)\succ id$ iff either $k>0$ or $k=0$ and $r/n^j>0$.
Another way to see the result is to note that $B(1,n)$ embedds into the affine group, and hence 
obtains such an ordering (see Alain Valette's remark).

Comment: Side remark: for $n\le -1$, $BS(1,n)$ is left-orderable but not bi-orderable.